# c++ template - expected type specifier in pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

This is a linked list and I'm trying to implement a function (Push) that adds items onto the top of the list.
For some reason **Node < ItemType > *nnode = new node< ItemType >;** inside the function is giving me an **error:  expected type-specifier before 'node'**.  This is how my professor taught me to implement stacks, linked lists, etc.

Am I implementing this wrong? I looked at other sites and they have almost identical code for linked lists.

```
#ifndef Linked_List_h
#define Linked_List_h

template <typename ItemType>
class Node
{
    public:
        ItemType Data;
        Node <ItemType> *next;
};

template <typename ItemType>
class Linked_List
{
        public:
        Node <ItemType> *start;
        Linked_List();
        int Push(ItemType newitem);
}
#endif
```

.

```
#include "Linked_List.h"

template <typename ItemType>
Linked_List <ItemType>::Linked_List(){
    start = NULL;
}

template <typename ItemType>
int Linked_List < ItemType >::Push(const ItemType newitem){
    Node < ItemType > *nnode = new node< ItemType >;  //not working
    nnode -> Data = newitem;
    nnode -> next = start;
    start = nnode;

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this help?

```
Node < ItemType > *nnode = new Node< ItemType >;
                               ^
                               typo correction
```

Comment: I am so sorry for the dumb question.. hopefully I won't get too many downvotes and banned for this.  Thank you

Comment: @Foxic: Not at all. On the contrary, you have asked the question in right way by providing (selected) well-formatted code along with the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'node' should be 'Node'...